# Как сделать сортировку облака меток в алфавитном порядке в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я через админку WordPress добавляю **новую метку "Якак"** она должна быть в самом конце,
так как **буква Я** последняя в алфавите. Но у меня метка **"Якак"** выводится на странице в самом начале списка в облаке тегов.

**Мой код для вывода меток:**

```js
<article class="Tags_Main_Block"> 
 <p class="tag-titles">МЕТКИ:</p>
 <div class="opase">

 <?php 
 wp_tag_cloud( [
    'smallest'  => 14,
    'largest'   => 14,
    'unit'      => 'pt',
    'number'    => 0,
    'format'    => 'flat',
    'separator' => "",
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'exclude'   => null,
    'include'   => null,
    'link'      => 'view',
    'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
    'echo'      => true,
    'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',  
] );
?>

</div>
 </article>
```

Comment: Заменить в orderby name на title

Comment: @noname228, не, по умолчанию там только name либо count можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, у вас включен фильтр `tag_cloud_sort` плагинами или темой.

Попробуйте добавить такой код в `functions.php` темы:

```
function my_tag_cloud_sort( $tags, $args ) {
    uasort( $tags, '_wp_object_name_sort_cb' );

    return $tags;
}


add_filter( 'tag_cloud_sort', 'my_tag_cloud_sort', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

Comment: Я выключил плагин, все равно не помогло. Но ставлю плюсик за старание.